# PHP error "No input file specified" when calling tinyMCE from a symlink

Tags: php, apache, tinymce, symlink, mod-fcgid

I use [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) with the PHP compressor. I would like to have it in a single folder, used by all the domains needing it on my server, instead of a copy for each site. However, since I know [it's not cross-domains](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/How-to_load_TinyMCE_crossdomain), I thought I could put it in a folder that each site could reach through a symlink.

But I'm getting this PHP error:

```
No input file specified.
```

I have the impression it has less to do with tinyMCE itself than with the symlink, but I don't have a clue.

Does anyone know?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
After lots of digging, it seems to have to do with Apache. PHP is run through FCGId, and it seems to be a permission error. However I get an error 500 if I run it with mod_php.

**SOLUTION:**
Putting it as a real answer so the question is not unanswered... See below

Comment: If you have a solution, then please answer this question and mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: And I answer and accept my own question??

Comment: Nabab: you edited your question adding the answer, it would be better if you could reply to your question using the "Your Answer" box below and marking your own reply as the answer, or perhaps a moderator can remove this from the Unanswered Questions list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put tinyMCE in the same folder as my static server, so in another vHost. The issue was a permission conflict; vHosts seem to not work well with one another. Putting the tinyMCE library in a folder outside /home (or /www) and beloging to root has solved the issue: the symlinks work fine on all domains and the PHP compressor does its job. :)